# Property "..." does not exist on type 'ServerContextJSONValue'. when I use useContext()

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wrote a Provider and give the type but when I use it with `useContext()` always have a ts error: Property "..." does not exist on type 'ServerContextJSONValue'. And I don't know what I'm missing.

Here the simple code I used:

```js
// Provider.tsx

interface ProviderContextType {
   text: string,
}

export const Context = createContext<ProviderContextType>({
   text: ''
});

function Provider(){
  ...

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={store}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

export default Provider;
```

```js
// Others.tsx

import { Context } from '@/provider/Provider';

const Others = () => {
   const { text } = useContext(Context); // <==== ts error: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'ServerContextJSONValue'. 

   return ...
}

export default Others;
```

Answer (score 1):

export the type.

```js
export interface ProviderContextType
```

and used it like:

```js
import { Context, ProviderContextType } from '@/provider/Provider';

const { text } = useContext<ProviderContextType>(Context);
```

will fix the problem.